# Rank of a Matrix under certain conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, definition, matrix-rank

I am a little confused about the rank of a matrix. When does the rank of a matrix equals to zero? Is rank of a matrix equal to zero when it is a zero matrix or the matrix has no elements in it? 
Thank you.

Comment: The rank of a matrix is zero if, and only if, the matrix is a null matrix. Does this help?

Comment: Thanks. What if the matrix is empty, i.e., no elements in it? Does the rank and nullity of this matrix even exist?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with empty matrix. if you mean something like a $0\times n$ matrix, then the rank would be (if I'm not mistaken) $n$, because $0\times n$ is a linear map from an $n$-dimensional vector space to $\{0\}$ and it maps everything to $0$.

Comment: Thank you, I got confused with myself. I understand it now. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rank of a matrix is the largest amount of linearly independent rows or columns in the matrix. So if a matrix has no entries (i.e. the zero matrix) it has no linearly lindependant rows or columns, and thus has rank zero. If the matrix has even just $1$ entry, then we have a linearly independent row and column, and the rank is thus $1$, so in conclusion, the only rank $0$ matrix is the zero matrix.

Comment: Thank you. So the zero matrix and empty matrix mean the same thing? I thought zero matrices are not considered to be empty matrices?

Comment: The empty matrix actually has no rows or no columns or both, but in all honesty I did not know such a thing existed until now.

Comment: O sorry, my bad. Empty matrices are mostly used for programming I guess. :)

Comment: But the lack of existence of rows or columns or both, attracts ambiguity, but I think empty matrices are useful in computer science.

Comment: No worries, hope that cleared things up!

Answer (score 0):

We have a theorem stating $Rank(M) + Nul(M) = dim(M)$. So if the basis for the null space is the standard basis (and if the matrix isn't square, an appropriate subset of the standard basis), we have $Nul(M) = dim(M)$. So $Rank(M) = 0$.

Remember that the null space is defined as $Ker(M) = \{ v: Mv = 0 \}$, for $v$ in the vector space.

Comment: Thank you. Could you briefly explain what does it mean by basis for the null space is the standard basis?

Comment: If you have a vector space $V$ with $dim(V) = n$, the null space is a subspace of $V$. So if the basis for the null space is the same basis as $V$, then we have $Ker(M) = V$. Now if $M$ isn't square (by having too few row vectors), then $V$ is a subspace of some other vector space, so we consider an appropriate subset of the standard basis of the parent space for $Ker(M)$.